# Install Cocoapods on El Capitan. "pod: command not found"

Tags: bash, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to install Cocoapods on El Capitan GM following the directions here: 
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692#issuecomment-113847612

Any time I try and run a 'pod' command it says that it can't be found. Everything's where it should be and I have no idea what's wrong. My terminal-fu isn't the strongest. Here's a dump of my terminal window.

```
Last login: Tue Sep 15 15:39:29 on ttys000
Shinji:~ Joey$ sudo gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
Shinji:~ Joey$ 
Shinji:~ Joey$ sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj
Shinji:~ Joey$ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby
Shinji:~ Joey$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
Shinji:~ Joey$ gem install cocoapods
Fetching: xcodeproj-0.26.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed xcodeproj-0.26.3
Fetching: fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Fetching: cocoapods-core-0.38.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-0.38.2
Fetching: cocoapods-0.38.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.38.2
Parsing documentation for xcodeproj-0.26.3
Installing ri documentation for xcodeproj-0.26.3
Parsing documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Installing ri documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-0.38.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-0.38.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.38.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.38.2
4 gems installed
Shinji:~ Joey$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Sofware/ruby/bin
Shinji:~ Joey$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/Joey/Sofware/ruby/bin
Shinji:~ Joey$ pod --version
-bash: pod: command not found
Shinji:~ Joey$
```